# When ng-disable triggered?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example I have:

```
<button ng-disabled="!isSomethingValid() || loading || disabled" ... class="btn btn-primary">
```

But, what is the condition for `ng-disable` attribute to evaluate it's expression?

Comment: The expression will be evaluated with each [digest](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/).

Comment: There's no "condition", angular evaluates all expressions it should evaluate, identifying it through the "ng-" prefix. What is exactly your issue ?

Comment: @Laurent S I need some validation for my form (disable submit btn if no one chechbox is checked) and trying to understand what is the better way to check it: write directive for check box or some function like isSomethingValid()

Answer (score 0):

ng-disabled is used to disable the DOM element when the value returns true.

```
    <button ng-disabled="mySwitch">Click Me!</button>
    <button type = "text" ng-click = "fnDemo();">Button</button>

$scope.mySwitch = true;

$scope.fnDemo = function(){
   $scope.mySwitch = !$scope.mySwitch; 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for attempt, but it's not I actually asked about. In your example you demonstrates the work (behavior) of ng-disable by changing the value of "mySwitch". <br/>And the question was about inner mechanism. (How/When ng-disable know that mySwitch changed). <br/>So I think that answer is given by @sdgluck "The expression will be evaluated with each digest."

Comment: give me your issue in jsfiddle.

Comment: or else use $watch for mySwitch then ng-disable come to know that mySwitch is changed.